# How can I return uncommitted changes in GIT after 'Abort Merge'?

Tags: git

I staged my changes, but did not commit them. Then I tried to make merge and then abort merge. Now all my changes are lost. Can I return them somehow?

Comment: What git command did you use to abort the merge?

Comment: I pressed Merge -> Abort Merge.. in the Git Gui tool.